# Converting WMV—from Ashampoo Snap 7—to MP4

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, wmv, x264

I've taken a (partial) desktop video using Ashamphoo Snap 7 in .wmv format. I couldn't find any option which allowed me to record in other formats. I want to convert it to .mp4, preferable x264 (I'm new to this and I've heard of this in several places, so I guess it's what everyone is using).

Input video details according to ffmpeg:

```
Input #0, asf, from 'input.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: @
    WMFSDKVersion   : 12.2.14393.726
    IsVBR           : 0
  Duration: 00:00:16.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2327 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: wmv1 (WMV1 / 0x31564D57), yuv420p, 1600x804, 2000 kb/s, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
```

I'm using `ffmpeg version N-82143-gbf14393`.

I've tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv output.mp4

ffmpeg -i input.wmv output.mp4 -crf 23
```

Both of these produce a video file which barely moves a frame; it moves a frame after a lot of time has passed.

Converting the video with Handbrake with the default settings (I just loaded the video, chose destination file and pressed "Encode") works as expected. I would prefer to use ffmpeg.

Here's a copy of [input.wmv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B28DuvEzq0XQOF9OQ05kLXpaLTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can use ffmpeg to capture the desktop and directly save it to any format it supports. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

Comment: @Mulvya, I didn't know about this; Thanks. I'd still use Ashampoo Snap as it allows me to highlight the portion of the desktop I want to record. I see this is possible too with ffmpeg albeit tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is variable frame rate. For such cases, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -vsync vfr output.mp4
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked. Can you please provide a brief explanation as to why?

Comment: ffmpeg, by default, creates a constant framerate MP4. When the input is variable rate, it duplicates frame so the result is constant rate. It uses a frame rate value necessary to preserve the fastest frame rate encountered in the source. For your file, that's 1000 fps.